# Replace pattern Java

Tags: java, regex

I am making a program that allows the user to set variables and then use them in their messages such as  `%variable1%`  and I need a way of detecting the pattern which indicates a variable  `(%STRING%)` . I am aware that I can use regex to find the patterns but am unsure how to use it to replace text.

I can also see a problem arising when using multiple variables in a single string as it may detect the space between 2 variables as a third variable
e.g. `%var1%`<-text that may be detected as a `variable->%var2%`, would this happen and is there any way to stop it?

Thanks.

Comment: maybe this can help you https://weblogs.java.net/blog/felipeal/archive/2008/10/adding_el_suppo.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A non-greedy regex would be helpful in extracting the variables which are within the 2 distinct % signs:

```
Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\%.*?\\%");
```

In this case if your String is `%variable1%mndhokajg%variable2%"` it should print

```
%variable1%
%variable2%
```

If your String is `%variable1%variable2%` it should print

```
%variable1%
```

`%variable1%%variable2%` should print

```
%variable1%
%variable2%
```

You can now manipulate/use the extracted variables for your purpose:

**Code:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            String tag = "%variable1%%variable2%";
            Pattern regex = Pattern.compile("\\%.*?\\%");

            Matcher regexMatcher = regex.matcher(tag);
            while (regexMatcher.find()) {
                System.out.println(regexMatcher.group());
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
```

Try playing around with different Strings, there can be invalid scenarios with % as part of the String but your requirement doesn't seem to be that stringent.

Comment: The essence of this seems to work thank you :) but I have attempted to make a pattern of my own which doesn't seem to be working properly, I currently have "%([.+])%" which I would assume would match %anything% but it doesn't, could you explain why?

Comment: @user2248702 you are not matching any character class hence would need to drop the square brackets. Try %(.+)% [here](http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html) with some of your test inputs.

Answer (score 1):

[Oracle's tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/matcher.html) on the Pattern and Matcher classes should get you started. Here is an example from the tutorial that you may be interested in:

```
import java.util.regex.Pattern; 
import java.util.regex.Matcher;

public class ReplaceDemo {

    private static String REGEX = "dog";
    private static String INPUT =
        "The dog says meow. All dogs say meow.";
    private static String REPLACE = "cat";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(REGEX);
        // get a matcher object
        Matcher m = p.matcher(INPUT);
        INPUT = m.replaceAll(REPLACE);
        System.out.println(INPUT);
    }
}
```

Your second problem shouldn't happen if you use regex properly.

Comment: The problem is I'm not sure how to do it with an unknown variable name, all it knows is that the variable name begins and ends with % and that it needs to find the string in the middle and get the corresponding string from a HashMap.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this method for variable detection and their replacements from a passed `HashMap`:

```
// regex to detect variables
private final Pattern varRE = Pattern.compile("%([^%]+)%");

public String varReplace(String input, Map<String, String> dictionary) {
    Matcher matcher = varRE.matcher( input );

    // StringBuffer to hold replaced input
    StringBuffer buf = new StringBuffer();

    while (matcher.find()) {
       // get variable's value from dictionary
       String value = dictionary.get(matcher.get(1));

       // if found replace the variable's value in input string
       if (value != null)
           matcher.appendReplacement(buf, value);
    }
    matcher.appendTail(buf);
    return buf.toString();
}
```